# ASP.NET Core 7 how to get hostBuilderContext with WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

In a skeleton ASP.NET Core 7 project with top level statements, this is what you get:

```
var builder = WebApplication.Create(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

I want to add a `DbContext` with:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EntityDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    var dbCfg = provider.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseConfig>();
    options.UseSqlServer(dbCfg);
});
```

I have a library which registers `appsettings.json` elements as DI services, which is where `IDatabaseConfig` would come from. To wire that up in the past I've done:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
    {
        // Provide environment override appsettings file
        var env = hostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment;
        services.RegisterAppSettings<Config>($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");
        .
        .
        .    
    })
```

With the top level statements and host builder approach in newer .NET where there is no `ConfigureServices` method, how do I get access to the `HostBuilderContext` in order to determine the `HostingEnvironment`?

Comment: Do you want to get HostingEnvironment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your library in `Host` like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
{
    var env = hostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment;
    services.RegisterAppSettings<Config>($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");
});
```

Or if you only need the environment name, so this is the way:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.RegisterAppSettings<Config>($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json");
```

Comment: Just curious, if I needed to go with `builder.Host` then which nuget package to I need to install. I'm not getting "find package" with intellisense and can't find the documentation page about it.

Comment: @StephenYork what is your .net version? Mine is .net6 and I can see it in the program.cs